# WIFI connectivity after 22.04 upgrade

Tags: wireless, 22.04

Updated my machine to 22.04 a few weeks ago.  My WiFi is no longer working.  Shows me no connections available, except a wired connection.  I am pretty new to UBUNTU, so I am not sure what to run to diagnose.  Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: See all the answers to [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos) and then [edit your question above](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1442020/edit) and add all the relevant information. Please do not put screenshots of photos of the terminal . Copy the output of the terminal and paste it directly into your question and format it as `code` using the {_} icon above the edit question window.

Answer (score 1):

First I would try doing the standard update procedure, `sudo apt update` followed by `sudo apt upgrade`.

If that doesn't work, this website I read says your problem could be with the kernel. Maybe trying to update the kernel via these commands:

`sudo apt-get update`
and then
`sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

may help fix the problem.

Here is the website:
https://www.technewstoday.com/ubuntu-wifi-not-working/

These tech newspapers seems like they are just fluff, but they have helped me fix problems before

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Useful command is

```
inxi -Fxmz
```

The output is the full information about your system. There is Network section where you can see what driver is used for wifi adapter.